# Pitch Accent Rule for -たり form?

Tags: pitch-accent

Is there a general rule of thumb for determining the pitch accent of the -たり form of verbs? Are they related to the pitch accent of the plain past form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is just た＼り, but if the verb already has a drop in it then the た＼り drop becomes irrelevant.

あがる￣→あがった￣→あがった＼り

さが＼る→さが＼った→さが＼ったり

たべ＼る→た＼べた→た＼べたり